# How costly is an OpenGL draw call, and how do I optimise them?

Tags: opengl, optimization

How costly is a draw call in OpenGL?

What are the ways to reduce the number of draw calls? I have seen people using `glMapBufferRange`, but I can't figure out how it improves the performance.

How much impact do draw calls have on the overall performance of a program?

Comment: `How much costly is a draw call?` , impossible to tell , each platform has it's own different cost (pc intel/nvidia/ati, mobile, consoles, embedded devices , etc). Multiply all of that with all the possible combinations to draw stuff (and there are a lot)

Comment: Thanks. .did you see My second query?

Comment: `What are the ways to reduce the number of draw calls?` Yes , draw less stuff, use instancing, batch small geometry into larger objects, don't draw (or add level of detail to) distant objects, frustum culling , occlusion culling, eliminate invisible geometry in complex scenes

Comment: Third one?   Man I Am like a program counter..incrementing the index of questions..lol

Comment: Does batch mean glmapbufferrange ?

Comment: We don't refer to books here, as there are no correct answers to "what book should I read".

Answer (score 1):

glDraw can cost a lot because it's the first place the driver actually knows what you want to draw.

The next glDraw call can cost anywhere from very little to a lot depending on how much render state you changed in between.

This means that for more efficient renders you need to group your objects into so that objects using the same state are rendered together. So the state changes between the glDraw calls are minimized. This is one thing that people can mean with batching.

You can also render more per draw call. This usually means instancing. This is the other meaning of batching.

`glMapBufferRange` is just a way of uploading data to the gpu and has little to do with

The final option to reduce cpu overhead is to move to the "next gen" graphics apis like Vulkan, DX12 or Metal. There the biggest cost in preparing for render is moved to creating the state objects that you then use for rendering. The win there is that the application code is responsible for not being stupid with destroying and recreating it.

Comment: Where to find a short example code that uses batch rendering

Comment: "You can also render more per draw call. This usually means instancing. This is the other meaning of batching." Instancing and batching are two completely discrete concepts.